# Removing elements from a list which contain too many characters in R

Tags: r, list, character

I am trying to find a way to remove elements from a list that meet a certain requirement. I want to remove all the elements of the list that have less than 30 characters, such as elements `[[2]], [[3]], [[5]]`, etc. You can see a screenshot of the list itself included in the following image:

[image]

I have tried using the `nchar` function, but I am not sure how to loop it over every single element within the list.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: apologies - rather new to all of this. I will make sure I do so in the future.

Comment: I'm neither in a rush nor begging for rep points, just offering some advice for new users of Stack sites. Come back!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply` to apply `nchar` on each element of the list, then use direct indexing with the results.

```r
vec <- list("hello world", "short", "this is a much longer string")
sapply(vec, nchar)
# [1] 11  5 28
vec[sapply(vec, nchar) > 10]
# [[1]]
# [1] "hello world"
# [[2]]
# [1] "this is a much longer string"
```

Or better (I forget that `nchar` operates on `list`s, too) as suggested by GKi:

```r
vec[nchar(vec) > 10]
```

An alternative is to use `Filter`, though it might be over-engineered for this.

```r
Filter(function(a) nchar(a) > 10, vec)
# [[1]]
# [1] "hello world"
# [[2]]
# [1] "this is a much longer string"
```

Comment: Or simple `vec[nchar(vec) > 10]`

Comment: god bless your soul! How did I not see such a simple solution...

Comment: Yeah, I keep forgetting that `nchar` works on lists, too, not just `character` vectors.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `keep` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
keep(vec, ~ nchar(.x) > 10)
```

#### data

```
vec <- list("hello world", "short", "this is a much longer string")
```